# java.lang.NullPointerException ... Initializing the JDBC MYSQL connection

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Please don't suggest me to use InternalFrame or Dialogs. I can't start the project from beginning. 
**Theme:** I'm building a GUI program to display mark-sheet. I've taken 3 JFrames & 1 simple class...

> Frame1.java

It's having 1 JTextField to enter roll_no. & 2 buttons to feedData in DB & showResult. feedData button calls Frame2 & showResult button calls Frame3.

> Frame2.java

For feeding data have several JTextFields & Buttons that transfer content to mySQL DB.

> Frame3.java

is a result window that fetches content from DB.

> Support.java

Contains static variables & getter-setter methods for them

```
 .....
 .....//contains in Support.java
     public boolean add() {
    query = "Insert into table1 (enroll,Sname,Fname,sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5 )values(?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        psmt.setString(1, enroll);
        psmt.setString(2, Sname);
        psmt.setString(3, Fname);
        psmt.setInt(4, sub1);
        psmt.setInt(5, sub2);
        psmt.setInt(6, sub3);
        psmt.setInt(7, sub4);
        psmt.setInt(8, sub5);
        int y = 0;
        y = psmt.executeUpdate();
        if (y == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

add() is called on pressing save button in Frame2.java  . . . If catch block is executing, why println(query)  printing NULL

Comment: What exception are you getting?  I'm guessing it's failing trying to create the statement.

Comment: **Side note**: Use `PreparedStatement`s, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say your problem is that you haven't initialized `conn`.

Comment: I guess, Ian McLaird... You're talking about conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);

Comment: Yes.  Are you certain that a valid `Connection` object has been assigned to `conn` before the `add()` method is called?  As posted, your code does not set that variable (though it may do so elsewhere in code you haven't posted).  Can you post the relevant part of a stack trace?

Comment: I've initiated Connection in Support.java that contain definition of add(). But add(); is called from Frame2.java .... Should I have to write Connection in Frame2.java or Make Connection object static in any one of the mentioned class. What to do next?

Comment: I'd be careful with a long-lived connection.  Things tend to go wrong in strange ways if you leave the connections hanging open without managing them somehow.  You'd probably be better off with a connection pool, but see my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on some of your question tags and responses in the comments to other answers and on the question itself, I'm presuming that somewhere in your code, you intend to call

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

This is not happening before your `add()` method is called.  In order to fix it, I'd recommend this (bulk of code borrowed from Vivek bhatnagar's answer):

```
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `table`
        (pid,tid,rid,tspend,description) VALUE 
        (?,?,?,?,?)");
    pstmt.setString(1, pid );
    pstmt.setString(2, tid);
    pstmt.setString(3, rid);
    pstmt.setInt(4, tspent);
    pstmt.setString(5,des );
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // whatever you want to do to handle the exception
} finally {
    // close your connection
}
```

If you're on Java 7, set up like this:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(/*sql here*/)) {
        // Your code here
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        // handle exceptions from the statement
    }
} catch (SQLException outerSqlEx) {
    // handle exceptions from connecting
}
```

How could I tell what your problem was (general help for `NullPointerException`)?

`NullPointerException` is only thrown when you try to call a method on a `null` variable (and at a few other specific times, as noted in the API documentation).  The easy way to locate a `NullPointerException` is to look for the line the stack trace indicates, and then look for the dots on the line.  There's only two lines in your `try` block that can throw a `NullPointerException`.

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
// could be here ----^
```

and

```
y = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
// or --^
```

So let's look at the dots.  The first one will throw when `conn` is `null`.  The second one will throw when `stmt` is `null`.  In your original code, which you've now edited in response to the other answers, you set the value of `query` after you called `conn.createStatement();`.  Since `query` was still null in your `catch` block, we know that it hadn't yet been set, and thus it must be the first one, so `conn` is `null` at that point in the program.

Furthermore, since the [API Documentation for createStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
implies that it will either return a valid `Connection` object or throw an `SQLException`, we can be pretty sure that `stmt` will never be `null` when `executeUpdate` is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone... The problem was null connection. You gave me satisfactory solution & now everything is working fine

Answer (score 0):

In your try block, you are **calling a method that is possible to throw an exception before setting the variable in question**:

```
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    query = "Insert into table1 (enroll,Sname,Fname,sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5 )values('" + getEnroll() + "','" + getSname() + "','"+getFname()+"',"+getSub1()+","+getSub2()+","+getSub3()+","+getSub4()+","+getSub5()+")";
```

Therefore, if your code fails on the conn.createStatement() line, it will enter the catch block without the query variable being initialized.

You can fix this simply by switching the order of the statements, or by putting the query line outside and before the try/catch blocks.

Comment: query isn't NULL anymore... But still I'm getting NullPointerException & obviously catch() is executing.. Plz Help..

Comment: My answer is not incorrect.  The variable "query" is null until it reaches the line where it is set, and it will not reach that line if an exception is thrown beforehand.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I have moved it as you told. Can you help me to fix it because it's executing catch()

Comment: The exception that is being thrown, likely from the line conn.createStatement(), is an entirely separate problem, though if it is also a NullPointerException, it likely is due to conn also being null.  You should be more careful about making sure you initialize your variables with values, as calling any method on a null value is an error, and rightfully so - it is nonsensical.

Comment: Everything is fine with query String. The problem persist only due to null Connection. How to deal with this.

Comment: It is impossible to say for certain, as it is a separate problem, not all the code has been provided, and I am not an expert on how the DriverManager class works.  Needless to say, your connection is null, and that is your problem.  As for why, I cannot say.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to what @Southpaw answered :

you can use something like this also :

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `table`
        (pid,tid,rid,tspend,description) VALUE 
        (?,?,?,?,?)");
pstmt.setString(1, pid );
pstmt.setString(2, tid);
pstmt.setString(3, rid);
pstmt.setInt(4, tspent);
pstmt.setString(5,des );
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Kindly Note its benefits:

```
1."Query is rewritten and compiled by the database server"

If you don't use a prepared statement, the database server will have to parse, and compute an execution plan for the statement each time you run it. If you find that you'll run the same statement multiple times (with different parameters) then its worth preparing the statement once and reusing that prepared statement. If you are querying the database adhoc then there is probably little benefit to this.

2."Protected against SQL injection"

This is an advantage you almost always want hence a good reason to use a PreparedStatement everytime. Its a consequence of having to parameterize the query but it does make running it a lot safer. The only time I can think of that this would not be useful is if you were allowing adhoc database queries; You might simply use the Statement object if you were prototyping the application and its quicker for you, or if the query contains no parameters.
```

Comment: While true, this doesn't do anything to address the NullPointerException that the OP is getting.